# Rooted my phone now it won't turn on

Tags: rooting, samsung

So a couple of minutes ago I rooted my phone ( well I think I did anyway ). Then all of a sudden, it went to the lock screen. So I tapped the bar where you put in your password and it was kind of glitching, I don't know how to explain it. I put in the first two letters of my password and it switched off. Pressed the power button, and it wouldn't turn on. I held it down for about a minute. Still nothing. I tried pressing the home, volume and power button at the same time but still nothing. I know at least half of you will say "That's why I hate 'one-click' rooting" or "Should have done your research!" but I'm not good at this stuff, and I knew it was a bad idea. I just wanted to get cheat droid for a game I really like. I don't understand these things. I'll give you some information, but I don't know if it will help. 
( By the way, my phone doesn't have a sim, it's my moms old phone, I have another question up telling what happened, but that's fixed )

Battery Percentage: 100% and it was charging

Version: 5.1.1

Name of phone : Samsung Galaxy Core Prime

Root app name: 360 Root

Please help me. I'm terrified, I never did this before :( Thank You.

EDIT : Alright, so I just restarted it somehow and it's on, turned out its not even rooted...?
I didn't link it up to my computer, as mine is broken. Does anyone have any idea on good rooting apps that are easy ( KingRoot won't work, and I don't have a computer that's working as I just said )

Answer (score 3, accepted):

My number one advice for people that are new to rooting, flashing etc. is, read at least 5 times before you do it. One-click-root Apps are almost a thing of the past nowadays because manufacturers are stepping up their game with securing their phones.

In your case, that means that you would have to reflash the stock ROM (I doubt that everything is still in tact after you tried to root it) and root then root it properly, for both of which you would need a working PC. Also, you will loose all the data that's on your phone.

For reinstalling the stock ROM, you'll first need to download a few things:

Drivers for your phone: http://downloadcenter.samsung.com/content/SW/201306/20130610184736640/SAMSUNG_USB_Driver_for_Mobile_Phones_v1.5.25.0-retail.exe

Odin: http://odindownload.com/

Stock firmware: https://www.sammobile.com/ (I can't link this to you directly since I don't know your model number, just click on firmware and search for your phone)

Install the drivers, unpack the firmware, connect your phone via USB, put it in download mode (turn it off and hold volume down, home and power at the same time) and start odin. On the right, you'll find many buttons named "Modem", "PDA" and so on. Click on the buttons and select the corresponding file in the firmware folder that you extracted earlier (For "PDA" select a file called "PDA" + extension etc). After all buttons have the corresponding path behind them (only leave those out which you don't have a respective file for, differs in some firmwares), click start.

Now your phone should be running stock Android again.
For rooting your phone, you need to download:

TWRP: https://dl.twrp.me/core33g/twrp-3.1.0-0-core33g.img.tar.html

SuperSu: https://download.chainfire.eu/696/SuperSU/

Open up Odin again (after connecting your phone and putting it into download mode), click on "PDA" and open the twrp file you just downloaded, then press start.

Disconnect your phone and restart it holding down volume up, home and power at the same time. You should see TWRP come up. Now connect your phone again and copy the SuperSu zip you downloaded earlier to your phone. Next, on your phone go to "Install" and select the SuperSu zip, then swipe to confirm. After that, click "Reboot System now" and when your phone booted, you should be rooted.

Good luck :D

Comment: Nice answer. Plus, the one-tap-rootkit apps tend to step way too over their scope.